# Fax Receiving Software

Tags: windows, ubuntu, fax

I am looking for a Fax receiving program. My company receives about 100 faxes a week. We get many junk faxes that we dont want to waste ink and paper for and we get many faxes that we would like stored electronically for archival purposes. Currently we are using Windows Fax console on XP. This has worked fairly well but has a lot of Failed Faxes when receiving (we dont use it for sending). Does anyone know a free or cheep Fax service for Windows XP or for Ubuntu? We dont want a web based fax service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've had very good luck with [hylafax](http://www.hylafax.org/content/Main_Page) works in linux, windows, mac, etc. You may need a front end to this to make it actually usable. We have our own here for our own purposes, but the back end is pretty good.

Comment: When You implement hylafax take look at great client for it http://yajhfc.berlios.de/